# email alert - recipient

Tags: email-alert

I have an email alert which is sent to the case owner (via workflow), but in the actual email received - there's always the general email account added automatically (total of 2 recipients). How can I disable this? I'd like to have only the recipient I choose.

Comment: have you checked the additional email section of your Email alert ?

Comment: yes, it's empty. The email address I'm referring to doesn't appear in the alert/template, it's the main address for our customer service and it's added automatically to all the email alerts.

Comment: any chance it is a different workflow/email alert that is getting fired? You can see from the debug logs

Comment: Check the Org wide email setting. maybe you are added your email will all email meesages.

Comment: I entered the Org wide settings, and the email is there all right. Where is it defined that an email address is added automatically to all email messages? I don't know where to look for it.